# Nil value params when using wash_out in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap

I am following the guide on the page of [Wash_Out](https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out#readme). And I'm getting the following error when I call one of the SOAP methods:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
```

The API controller looks like this

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController

  include WashOut::SOAP

  soap_action "integer_to_string",
              :args   => :integer,
              :return => :string
  def integer_to_string
    render :soap => params[:value].to_s
  end

  soap_action "concat",
              :args   => { :a => :string, :b => :string },
              :return => :string
  def concat
    render :soap => (params[:a] + params[:b])
  end
end
```

The request to the WSDL runs fine. I have this also listed as a [bug report](https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out/issues/3) for the said library. I couldn't find whether this is a Rails problem or a Wash Out problem. The params variable is available in normal controller actions.

Versions:

- Rails 3.1.3
- wash_out 0.2.3
- Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug of Savon actually %). Which got down on wash_out. To fix this for now just add "gem 'savon'" to your Gemfile. Will be fixed in upcoming version.

You should either upgrade to wash_out 0.3.0. It contains a lot of improvements and bug fixes.

Comment: Actually I'm the same person that opened the issue on GitHub on this. :) I forgot to close this one and add the information. Sorry